# Joining two tables with common primary key but bring in additional columns that is causing cartesian

Tags: sql, plsql, toad

I'm trying to join two tables similar to below. Is it possible to even join and get data without cartesian products?

Would appreciate any help, Thanks!

Table 1
: Primary Key Column : Field2
: R1                 : C1
: R1                 : C2
: R2                 : C3

Table 2
: Primary Key Column : Field3
: R1                 : O1
: R1                 : O2
: R3                 : O3

Table 3 - joined
: Column1      : Column2   : Column3
: R1           : C1        : 01
: R1           : C2        : 02
: R2           : C3        : 
: R3           :    : 03

Comment: Hi - unfortunately this isn’t a code writing service. Please provide sample data, the result you are trying to achieve and show the SQL that you have managed to write on your own. Then ask a specific question

Comment: @nickW sorry that wasn't my intent. I'll update my question with the sample query. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (pk, field2) as
  3    (select 'R1', 'C1' from dual union all
  4     select 'R1', 'C2' from dual union all
  5     select 'R2', 'C3' from dual
  6    ),
  7  t2 (pk, field3) as
  8    (select 'R1', '01' from dual union all
  9     select 'R1', '02' from dual union all
 10     select 'R3', '03' from dual
 11    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 12  --
 13  -- Calculate row number; that new - RN - column will be then used as supplemental JOIN
 14  -- condition
 15  t1_new as
 16    (select pk, field2,
 17            row_number() over (partition by pk order by field2) rn
 18     from t1
 19    ),
 20  t2_new as
 21    (select pk, field3,
 22            row_number() over (partition by pk order by field3) rn
 23     from t2
 24    ),
 25  -- all PK values, as your final result should contain all of them so you can't just
 26  -- use table1 or table2 as none of them contains all PK values
 27  all_pks as
 28    (select pk, rn from t1_new
 29     union
 30     select pk, rn from t2_new
 31    )
 32  -- finally:
 33  select p.pk, a.field2, b.field3
 34  from all_pks p left join t1_new a on a.pk = p.pk and a.rn = p.rn
 35                 left join t2_new b on b.pk = p.pk and b.rn = p.rn
 36  order by p.pk, a.field2, b.field3;

PK FIELD2     FIELD3
-- ---------- ----------
R1 C1         01
R1 C2         02
R2 C3
R3            03

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Littlefoot !!! I'll try the above query and will keep you posted if it works :)

Comment: THANK YOU!! exactly what I was looking for and the query returns the distinct values for the primary key :)

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad if it helped.